# How can I speed up Youtube video load time on Fancybox

Tags: performance, caching, youtube, fancybox, load-time

Currently when user clicks on play icon, Fancybox open up Youtube video lightbox pretty quickly.  Youtube video begins to auto=play but video clip is taking a very long time to load up>  How can I speed up the video loading?